# Use horizontal scroll in a reactjs project

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, scroll

I have a reactjs web that manages a web app. The main appears in every page of my web app, how can I add a horizontal scroll in my app just modifying the main?

Answer (score 1):

I am uncertain if this is what you want to achieve, but from your explanation it sounds as if you want one element, your `main` to scroll horizontally while the other components stay where they are.

If this is correct, you can simply add `overflow-x: scroll` to your `main` element styling with **CSS** like this:

```
main {
    overflow-x: scroll
}
```

Or with **inline styling** on your JSX element like this:

`<main style={{ overflowX: 'scroll' }} />`

You will be able to scroll horizontally as long as the content of your `main` element exceeds the width of your `main`.

For example, the top `div` in my snippet is wider than the `main` (300px vs 200px), so the `main` becomes scrollable.
The bottom `div` is smaller than the `main` (100px vs 200px), so the `main` isn't scrollable as their is nothing outside of it's boundary to scroll to.

```js
const SFC = props => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <main style={{ overflowX: 'scroll' }}>
      <div className="content" style={{ width: '300px' }} />
    </main>
    <main style={{ overflowX: 'scroll' }}>
      <div className="content" style={{ width: '100px' }} />
    </main>
  </React.Fragment>
);

ReactDOM.render(<SFC/>, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. My main code is like this :                                                       class Main extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <main style={{ overflowX: 'scroll' }}>
          <Switch>
            {/* Root path */}
            <Route exact path='/' component={Login}/>
   /*..............................
   ..............................
   .............................. 
   */
   
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
But it doesnt´t work yet. A fault appears in the main tag closure.

Comment: It appears as if the content in your `main` does not exceed the boundaries of your `main`. So `overflowX` won't do anything as their is nothing to scroll to. I have updated my answer with a code snippet as a demonstration.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark my answer as "accepted answer" and give it an upvote. That way I get some reputation for it.